# Как реализовать свойство в подклассе, наследуемое от класса и интерфейса (если в интерфейсе и классе это свойство разных типов)?

Tags: kotlin

```kotlin
interface A {
    var a: String
    fun foo() {
        println("interface A")
    }
}
open class B() {
    open var a: Int = 1
    open fun foo() {
        println("class B")
    }
}
class C: A, B() {
    override var a // ????????????????????
    override fun foo() {
        super<A>.foo()
    }
}
```

Comment: И какой в этом смысл? По сути - никак. Либо наследоваться от класса, либо имплементировать интерфейс, но не и то и другое, если у них есть конфликтующие по типу поля.

Comment: Спасибо. Просто про методы понятно, а про свойства...

Comment: Абсолютно точно так же, как и с методами. В котлин публичные поля - на самом деле не публичные, а просто приватные поля, к которым добавлены геттеры и сеттеры. Геттеры и сеттеры - точно такие же методы, как и любые другие методы.